# nexus 7 proximity sensor

Tags: android, mobile, sensors

I'm trying to create an app that utilizes the proximity sensor in most Android phones. But, since I can't really emulate getting my face close to an emulator, I'm debugging on my Nexus 7. Unfortunately, nothing is happening in regards to the proximity sensor.

So, I guess my question can be answered pretty easily, but, does the Nexus 7 even have a proximity sensor? If it does I'll post some code, but I have a feeling that may be my problem...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the specs](http://www.google.com/nexus/#/7/specs), the Nexus 7 doesn't have a proximity sensor. And it makes sense to not have one, as you're never going to talk on it.

Comment: That's what I thought. There are a lot of sites out there though that say it does for whatever reason...

Thanks.

Comment: Probably because they see the little round spot next to the webcam, but that's probably just the ambient light sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Felix is right, there is no proximity sensor like on the nexus 4.
There is a magnetic sensor Between the z and mic button on the standard keyboard when in upright portrait mode. It behaves like a [shmitt trigger hall effect sensor](http://bildr.org/2011/04/various-hall-effect-sensors/). 
Finally, I have noticed that touches can be sensed on the capacitive touchscreen even without physical contact. Experimentation may yield interesting and innovative results. Or a loss of hair. 
Best of luck.